# How Can I Efficiently Adjust Difficulty on a Pedal Generator without Mechanical Gears?

Tags: power, analog, torque, power-generation, gear

I'm charging a battery using pedal power, like this:

```
pedals -> brushless generator -> rectifier -> charge controller -> battery
```

I'd like to be able to adjust the difficulty at the pedals electronically, so that the someone can pedal harder ("uphill") and charge the battery faster, or they can pedal more easily and charge the battery more slowly.

I can't use mechanical gears to do this, I can't modify the generator, and I only have one battery.

My first thought is to place some sort of "difficulty device" like this:

```
pedals -> brushless generator -> rectifier -> (difficulty device?) -> charge controller -> battery
```

I guess one option would be for the "difficulty device" to contain a variable resistor in parallel (between positive and negative lines). With zero resistance, the pedals should move easily because the circuit is shorted and doing nothing (except generating a little heat)... Correct? And with infinite resistance, all the electricity would go to charging the battery.

But a parallel resistor only allows me to decrease difficulty, not increase it. I could increase difficulty by adding a variable resistor in series, but that just wastes energy.

I've considered using some type of variable transformer to increase voltage, but I'm not certain if/how that would change the difficulty at the pedal, especially when the charge controller just regulates it back down to the battery voltage.

I'd really appreciate ideas on how to do this electronically and efficiently. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you will find that the greater the load on the generator (in other words, the lower the parallel resistance) the greater the effort required. Consequently, varying the "parallel resistance" allows you to vary the extra "difficulty". Make sure that the battery cannot discharge through this extra load when, for example, pedalling stops.

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct.

Lower the load resistance, higher the current, greater the effort required and vice-versa.

Increasing the charging current increases the effort and vice-versa.

You would need to adjust the charging current.

Answer (score 0):

In electric motors and generators, speed is voltage and torque is current. You want to reduce the current.

The obvious way is to simply put a (variable) resistor in series in the circuit somewhere, to reduce the overall current. This will also waste power, though.

You could use a transformer to trade voltage for current without losing much power, but it won't be adjustable, unless you manage to find a surplus three-phase variac (or connect three variacs to the same knob).

You could use a buck converter after the rectifier to trade voltage for current. I think this would be my preferred option. A buck converter simply uses PWM to disconnect the generator for say half the time (so the difficulty averages out to half - you can adjust this ratio), then uses an inductor to smooth out the current so it's not pulsing on and off. You can build your own or buy one as a module, but make sure it's big enough to handle the amount of power involved (about 200W at a guess?).